# How to Modify the JOIN Clause in a Collection, Varien_Db_Select, or Zend_Db_Select

Tags: filter, query

I need to modify this:

```
$select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
```

query is:

```
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` 
    ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id 
        AND cat_index.store_id=1 
        AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) 
        AND cat_index.category_id='14'
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` 
    ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id 
        AND price_index.website_id = '1' 
        AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `brand_idx_5` 
    ON brand_idx_5.entity_id = e.entity_id 
        AND brand_idx_5.attribute_id = '139' 
        AND brand_idx_5.store_id = 1 
        AND brand_idx_5.value = '5'
```

how to remove this `INNER JOIN`?:

```
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `brand_idx_5` 
    ON brand_idx_5.entity_id = e.entity_id 
        AND brand_idx_5.attribute_id = '139' 
        AND brand_idx_5.store_id = 1 
        AND brand_idx_5.value = '5'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? That inner join appears because you most probably have a filter in the layered nav on the brand attribute, for the brand with the id 5. remove the filter and the inner join should not be there anymore

Comment: I am trying to get total product count for filter attribute. But it must not be affected by filter. I decide to modify Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute ->getCount()

Comment: How to remove the filter ?

Comment: I was suggesting to remove the filter from the UI, because your question was not clear. not my comment does not seam to have any value.

Comment: i guess that Arnold,you want to remove filter from specific category

Comment: I want to remove filter attribute if there is no product, but I can't use $_item->getCount() because it depends on checked attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating `Varien_Db_Select` (`Zend_Db_Select`)  are kind of tricky and hacky. You have to extract the `FROM` clause from it, do some manipulation, remove the `FROM` in your cloned `$select`, and add this modified `FROM` clause back into `$select`. In summary...

```
$select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->getSelect();
$fromAndJoins = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM)

// $fromAndJoins is an array. Loop through each and rebuild your array 
// for the FROM clause, first INNER JOIN clause, and second INNER JOIN clause
// Call them $from, $join1, and $join2

$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);  // wipe the original FROM and INNER JOINs
$select->from($from);
$select->join($join1);
$select->join($join2);
```

There might be a better way, but this is the only way I'm aware of, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the attribute you can remove it from collection:

```
$productCollection->removeAttributeToSelect('attribute_name');
```

Comment: Do you mean $productCollection->removeAttributeToSelect('brand'); ?

Comment: Yes. I mean this.

Comment: doesn't work, o I don't how to do it. 

`$select = clone $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->removeAttributeToSelect('condition')->getSelect();`

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue for collections with custom left joins defined in `_initSelect()` method, where we needed a query to implement a right join instead of left and reset columns.

Here is example of how it can be done inside your custom model collection class:

```
public function getMyCustomCollection()
{
    $select = $this->getSelect();

    $select
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::FROM)
    ;

    parent::_initSelect();

    $select->joinRight(
        ['invoice' => 'sales_flat_invoice'],
        'main_table.invoice_id = invoice.entity_id',
        []
    );

    return $this;
}
```